# How to join these two lists in Python to form a path?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
remote =  ['django', 'django/genelaytics', 'django/genelaytics/manage.py', 'django/genelaytics/rsync/rsync-HEAD-20121003-2147GMT']
```

I found the parent directory of each list using for loop like this:

```
for i in remote:
    os.path.dirname(i)
```

I have another list which I get from the user selection(includes only the file name) like this:

```
choices = ['django', 'genelaytics', 'manage.py']
```

To process this list I am going to need the parent directory which I already have using the `for loop` I mentioned above. How do I use these two lists to get the full path of each file like this and process them?

```
django/genelaytics
```

**Edit**:
The list may not always start from the top hierarchy. Also the top hierarchy may not be always same. That's why I wanted to find out the full parent directory for each file. For example:

```
    django
    genelaytics
    .project
    .pydevproject
    manage.py
    fileupload
    __init__.py
    __init__.pyc
    form.html~
    form
    forms.py
    forms.pyc
    models.py
    models.pyc
```

The list may contain manage.py and forms.py. `The full path for manage.py may be: django/genelaytics/manage.py and for forms.py django/genelaytics/forms/forms.py`. It's actually a tree structure. Also `django/genalaytics` is dynamically generated and differs for every user. So, it can't be static.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `os.path.join` and argument expansion to do that:

```
>>> import os
>>> choices = ['django', 'genelaytics', 'manage.py']
>>> os.path.join(*choices)
'django/genelaytics/manage.py'
>>> os.path.join(*choices[:-1])
'django/genelaytics'
```

This assumes that the elements in `choices` are safe (i.e. no `../../manage.py`), as stuff like this can happen:

```
>>> choices = ['django', 'genelaytics', '/etc/passwd']
>>> os.path.join(*choices)
'/etc/passwd'
```

---

Looks like OP was actually looking for:

```
>>> [os.path.join(*choices[:i + 1]) for i in range(len(choices))]
['django', 'django/genelaytics', 'django/genelaytics/manage.py']

>>> root = '/test/foo/'
>>> [os.path.join(root, *choices[:i + 1]) for i in range(len(choices))]
['/test/foo/django', '/test/foo/django/genelaytics', '/test/foo/django/genelaytics/manage.py']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to get the  full path of every elements in the list. Using (*choices) give the path of last element of list only and it's not practical to use slicing for every element. What might be the solution? Thanks again.

Comment: So you are looking for something like `['django', 'django/genelaytics', 'django/genelaytics/manage.py']`?

Comment: @user1881957: Then `[os.path.join(*choices[:i + 1]) for i in range(len(choices))]` should work.

Comment: Edit your answer. It might be helpful for someone with the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Actually there is a flaw in this approach. May be my question is not very clear. Problem is: the list may not contain the elements for the top hierarchy: For example a= ['utils', 'hello'] The real hierarcy would be: /home/nfs/django/utils and then /home/nfs/django/utils/hello.

Comment: See my edited question. The value of variable root is not static.

Comment: Can you help me out of this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20869/discussion-between-user1881957-and-blender)